# Laravel project on BitBucket

Tags: git, laravel, bitbucket

I am putting my first Laravel project into a production server. I have developed it in Windows environment. In the production server I have found that folder names under resources folder and blade file names should be in lowercase characters. Otherwise it won't work.

So I have changed my folder+file names into lowercase characters through Atom text editor in local machine. Then I have pushed the project into BitBucket. From there, I will clone my project into production server. But the problem is, folder+file names are still in uppercase characters in BitBucket after committing.

I have removed the repository and then created a new repository and then pushed the project to BitBucket. Still my folder names are in uppercase characters. I have used this commands

- git init
- git remote add origin https://xxxx@bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxxx_xxx.git
- git push -u origin --all

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [git mv](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv) to let git know about changes in case.

```
git mv -f Filename filename
```

Git is case insensitive by default so you need to be explicit.

To change this default behaviour you can set

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```